# Collections.addAll, Queue<Integer> and int[]

Tags: java

The following code doesn't work though it seems quite correct:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Jaba {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] array = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            array[i] = rand.nextInt(30);
        }
        Queue<Integer> que = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
        Collections.addAll(que, Arrays.asList(array));
    }

}
```

What should be fixed?

Comment: Can you explain the "doesn't work" part? Do you get a Stacktrace, or just wrong or unexpected data? What would you assume this does, but what does it? etc.

Comment: method addAll in class java.util.Collections cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.Collection<? super T>,T[]
  found: java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>,java.util.List<int[]>
  reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that argument type java.util.List<int[]> conforms to formal parameter type T[]

Comment: should be `Integer`, not `int`

Comment: Changing int[] to Integer[] haven't solved the problem. Still just the same error except that ...java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` takes an array of objects. (It's the only option, as it can't return a `List<int>`.)

When you pass an `int[]` to `Arrays.asList`, it will be interpreted as a singleton array containing one `int[]`.

You'll have to

- Change to a for-loop:

  ```
  for (int i : array)
      que.add(i);
  ```

  or
- change the type of `array` from `int[]` to `Integer[]`.

  This would allow you to do

  ```
  que.addAll(Arrays.asList(array))
  ```

  or,

  ```
  Collections.addAll(que, array);
  ```

The reason that `Collections.addAll(que, Arrays.asList(array))` fails is that it takes a `T...` as second argument, which is really an **array** and not a **List**.

Comment: What if I change int[] to Integer[]?

Comment: Then doing `que.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));` should work well.

Comment: Yes, que.addAll and Integer[] in pair work fine. Still that seems strange why Collections.addAll doesn't work. Thanks dude.

Comment: That's because it takes a `T...` (an array of `T`) as argument and `Arrays.asList` returns a `List<T>`.

Comment: Java just has to complicate everything. This could be easily done with Python, Typescript or JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

> method addAll in class java.util.Collections cannot be applied to given types; required: java.util.Collection,T[] found: java.util.List,java.util.List reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that argument type java.util.List conforms to formal parameter type T[]

Because List< int[]> != List< Integer>. Arrays.asList(T ...) returns T[], so giving it an int[] will return a List of int[].

Why not just use:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    Queue<Integer> que = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
           que.add(rand.nextInt(30));
    }
```

Do you really need the int[] array? If not, the above should do the job.

-- Edit, with Collections.addAll:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    Queue<Integer> que = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
    Integer[] toAdd = new Integer[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < toAdd.length; ++i) {
           toAdd[i] = rand.nextInt(30);
    }
    Collections.addAll(que, toAdd); // T ... Elements can be either separate elements, or a T[] array.
```

Comment: Yes Yhn, you are quite right, that is much better, but I'm learning Java and currently studying the Collections class.

Comment: If you'd change your int[] or Integer[] array with a Collection (List/Queue/etc) you can use Collections.addAll(que, collection) (updated the answer with that)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [google guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html) `Ints` class:

```
    que.addAll(Ints.asList(array));
```

Where `Ints.asList()` converts an `int[]` to a `List<Integer>` which is what you need.